# Express Rational number as sum of prime fractions

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Suppose you have a rational number x given by:

$$ x = \frac pq $$

Then given an error bound $ \epsilon $ give x as:

$$ x  - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{j_i}{k_i} \le \epsilon $$

where n is minimized and j,k are prime.

I thought about this problem while working on something in Computer Science. Even if a solution is not possible I would appreciate how to think and solve this problem (preferably efficiently).

Edit1: People have pointed out that for arbitrarily large j,k this is always possible. To be more clear rather than minimize n we want to minimize the Kolmogorov complexity of the series :
$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{j_i}{k_i}  $

Comment: Why do you care that $j,k$ are prime?  It makes sense to ask that they be coprime.  Then you can use [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations)

Comment: It depends on how you wish the result to be achieved. Intuition suggests that this is always solvable for $n=1$, as long as there are no bounds to $j,k$, but their generating algorithm will not be efficient.

Comment: Your quantifiers aren't clear.  I'd expect $\epsilon =0$ even if $n=1$, for example.  Take, say, $x=\frac 34$.  Randomly choosing $p_{1000}=7919$ as a numerator we look for primes near $\frac 43\times 7919\sim 10559$.  As it happens, we are in luck, as $10559$ is prime, and we check that $\frac {7919}{10559}=.74999763$ I expect you could do a lot better with a little searching.